# Solve for $\theta$ in $\sum M_y = - I \dot\Theta(\dot\psi cos(\theta)+p) $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Trying to solve gyroscopic equations of motion, but stuck trying to isolate $\theta$ in the equation below.

$\sum M_y = - I \dot\Theta(\dot\psi cos(\theta)+p) $

We know $M_y, I, \dot\psi$ and $p$ but not $\theta$ or $\dot\theta$

Appreciate any guidance

Thanks

Update: Here's what I've managed so far.
I've tried to re-arrange it to get $\theta$, but I'm really not sure where to start to solve it. The re-arranged equation becomes:

$\theta=cos^{-1}\Bigl( - (\frac{\sum M_y}{I \dot\theta}-p) / \dot\psi \Bigr)$

But $\dot\theta$ is a function of $\theta$, so I'm not sure where to go next.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Hi, Yes I've tried to re-arrange it to get $\theta$, but I'm really not sure where to start to solve it. The re-arranged equation becomes:

Comment: i'd add your working to the question if i was you to avoid it being closed on the grounds of no effort shown by the OP

Comment: Duly noted. Original post updated with progress.

Comment: Engaging question, but a tad unclear.  I wish you would define your terms more explicitly; then I might give it a shot.  Cheers!

Comment: Not totally sure what you mean.
Nevertheless... I just realised that in the context of my problem the $\dot\psi cos(\theta)$ term is negligible, so I don't need to worry about $\theta$ at all!
Still... Interesting to know the solution...